# PYTHON: Send email using entry/button tkinter error

Tags: python, email, tkinter

I have this program that uses tkinter as my GUI. My program clicks on a button to send an email to. Once they click on that button, an entry/button will also appear so that the user can enter their email to send a message. Once that button is clicked, that is when the message will be sent to that email.

However, I get this error right when I clicked on the first button (Send An Email):

```
{'': (555, b'5.5.2 Syntax error. i72sm3973288itc.11 - gsmtp')}
```

The error happens before I even get to enter the email address on the entry box. I am trying to successfully enter an email address and send a message to that email, but failing so far.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib

root = Tk()


def create_button():
    email_btn = Button(root, text="SEND AN EMAIL", fg='blue',
                       command=lambda: get_email())
    email_btn.pack()


def get_email():
    entry_email = StringVar()
    entry_email.get()

    email = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_email)
    email.pack()

    send_btn = Button(root, text="SEND", command=send_email_info(entry_email))
    send_btn.pack()


def send_email_info(entry_email):
    try:

        prompt_msg = "THIS IS A MESSAGE FOR THE EMAIL"
        user = '*****@gmail.com'
        password = '******'

        sender = entry_email.get()

        subject = "EMAIL TEST "
        message = "Subject: {} \n\n{}".format(subject, prompt_msg)
        send_to = ("{}".format(sender))

        mail = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.login(user, password)
        mail.sendmail(user, send_to, message)
        mail.close()
        print("Success Email!")
        email_cmd = Label(root, text="Email Sent!")
        email_cmd.pack()

    except Exception as x:
        print("FAILED")
        print(x)

def main():
    create_button()
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Have you set up your gmail account to allow you to send messages through external services?

Comment: `command=` needs callback - it means function's name without `()` and parameteres. If you do `command=function()` then you get `result = function()` , `command=result` and it means `function()` is executed before you even click. TO assign function with parameters you can use `lambda` - `command=lambda:function()`

Comment: @SamGomena Yes. I had one created so it is with *** as of right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need `entry_email.get()` this just gets the string from the widget, and you are not capturing the return value anyways. You **do** need `entry_email.get()` instead of `entry_email` as the argument to your function for `send_btn`. The reason it is evaluating prematurely is because you are not using a `lambda` function like you do in the first part of your code (like you should every time you include an argument with your callback to your function). I think you are looking for code like:

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib

root = Tk()


def create_button():
    email_btn = Button(root, text="SEND AN EMAIL", fg='blue',
                       command=lambda: get_email())
    email_btn.pack()


def get_email():
    entry_email = StringVar()
    # entry_email.get() # you don't need this, it does nothing

    email = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_email)
    email.pack()
    # function below needs a lambda
    send_btn = Button(root, text="SEND", command=lambda: send_email_info(entry_email.get()))
    send_btn.pack()


def send_email_info(entry_email):
    try:

        prompt_msg = "THIS IS A MESSAGE FOR THE EMAIL"
        user = '*****@gmail.com'
        password = '******'

        sender = entry_email

        subject = "EMAIL TEST "
        message = "Subject: {} \n\n{}".format(subject, prompt_msg)
        send_to = ("{}".format(sender))

        mail = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.login(user, password)
        mail.sendmail(user, send_to, message)
        mail.close()
        print("Success Email!")
        email_cmd = Label(root, text="Email Sent!")
        email_cmd.pack()

    except Exception as x:
        print("FAILED")
        print(x)

def main():
    create_button()
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, I get an error saying: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when I try to enter an email address.

Comment: @smokingpenguin Oh I see you were calling `.get()` inside `send_email_info()` too. I guess I didn't need to add it to `get_email()`. I edited my answer and it should resolve that